# How to add gridlines to an already generated chart in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a bubble chart which is already generated. I need to add/remove gridlines on the same chart based on a checkbox which user can select.

I tried something like the following but it didn't work.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var chart = $('#bubble-chart-container').highcharts();
    chart.options.xAxis[0].gridLineWidth = 1;
    chart.options.yAxis[0].gridLineWidth = 1;
    chart.reflow();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `chart.update` ([API link](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update)) method like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="addButton">Add lines</button>
<button id="removeButton">Remove lines</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  ...
});


$('#addButton').click(function() {
  chart.update({
    xAxis:{
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },
    yAxis:{
        gridLineWidth: 1
    }
  });
});

$('#removeButton').click(function() {
  chart.update({
    xAxis:{
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis:{
        gridLineWidth: 0
    }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/1c3atpm0/)